# Capturing HTTP Web Requests from c# webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using the c# webbrowser control to visit a web page, and this page contains some javascript which makes an AJAX web request. Is it possible to capture this request (specifically the headers of the request)?
I came across this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control however it seems it will not work with VS2012/NET4.5.
Thanks

Comment: You can try using Fiddler with proxy enabled on your web.config. http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore). It allows you to integrate HTTP/HTTPS traffic viewing and modification capabilities into your .NET application.